# ruby - reading files with utf-8 4 byte characters

Tags: ruby, file, csv, utf-8

I have csv file with utf-8 characters, for example - `Łódź`. When I tried to read the file using

```
file=File.open(file, "r:ISO-8859-1:UTF-8")
```

it doesn't encode the character right.

This works with other utf-8 character like `Göteborg`, but not with all of them.

How do I read a file that can encode all the UTF-8 characters?

Comment: Please give more details such as your OS, the encoding used in your console (or however you can see the output of your program), your Ruby version and the encoding of the input file (are you sure it's UTF-8? Because your `r:ISO-8859-1:UTF-8` says otherwise).

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to read file in `LATIN` encoding. `Göteborg` is being read correctly because there is “o umlaut” in ASCII-8/ISO-8859-1.

```
File.open(file, "r:UTF-8")
```

does the trick.

BTW, whether you are using ruby 2+, you might omit `"r:…"` part at all: the files are now being read in `UTF-8` by default.